# better python pattern for exception handler in a loop?

Tags: python

I found myself using the following pattern in my tests quite often:

```
def test(params):
    e_list = []
    for p in params:
        try:
            run_test(p) # Or a block of codes that can continue or break
        except Exception as e:
            e_list.append(e)
    assert isEmpty(e_list), 'error encountered: {}'.format(e_list)
```

I find myself rewriting this pattern quite often, especially with long code block for the loop that has some flow controls with `continue` and `break`.  I am wondering if there is a python-ic wrapping to this pattern.

I have thought about a wrapper function like this:

```
def assert_all_tests(test_list):
    e_list = []
    for t in test_list:
        try:
            t()
        except Exception as e:
            e_list.append(e)
    assert isEmpty(e_list), 'error encountered: {}'.format(e_list)

def test(params):
    assert_all_tests([functools.partial(run_test, p) for p in params])
```

But I dislike this approach because it wrapped away the loop. There is no way for callable `t` to do flow control of the loop with `continue` or `break` (there is no loop any more, only a list comprehension).

Another approach is to use a context class like this:

```
def test(params):
    ErrorHandler.clearErrorList()
    for p in params:
        with ErrorHandler():
            run_test(p) # or code block that can continue or break
    ErrorHandler.assertEmptyErrorList()
```

where `ErrorHandler` would be a class with appropriate `__enter__` and `__exit__` and keep an error list in a class variable.  But I feel that at the `test` function level, this is not any simpler than the original pattern: since there is no way for a `ErrorHandler` instance to know when a loop has began and ended, I still have to write the pre- and post- loop fixtures.

I'd like to hear idea of approaches to wrap around this pattern.  Thanks.

## EDIT

Thank you all for your comments.

New approach inspired by @paul-cornelius's answer

```
class ResultCollector(object):
    def __init__(self, raise_on_error=True):
        self.result_list = []
        self.raise_on_error = raise_on_error

    def do(self, func, *args, **kwds):
        '''do can only deal with code block that can be wrapped into a function'''
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwds)
        except Exception as e:
            if not isinstance(e, AssertionError) and self.raise_on_error:
                raise
            self.result_list.append(e.message or e)
        else:
            self.result_list.append(None)
            
    def assertClean(self):
        assert not [x for x in self.result_list if x is not None], 'test results: {}'.format(self.result_list)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.result_list = []
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, exc_t, exc_i, exc_tb):
        if exc_t:
            return None
        self.assertClean()
        return True

def test():
    def can_be_refactored_into_func(p):
        assert p%3, 'failed {}'.format(p)

    def condition_for_skip(p):
        return p%2

    def condition_for_break(p):
        return p>5
    
    with ResultCollector() as rc:
        for p in range(10):
            if condition_for_skip(p):
                rc.result_list.append('skipped {}'.format(p))
                continue
            if condition_for_break(p):
                rc.result_list.append('ended {}'.format(p))
                break
            rc.do(can_be_refactored_into_func, p)
```

It works pretty well when the code into loop block can be divided up into functions like above.

Comment: Why are you collecting errors in a list instead of throwing at the first error encountered?

Comment: Because there are some tests that we want to see a list of all errors that will be thrown instead of the first one because we decide on the course of action to fix it.  It sometimes inform me where the underlying issue is when I have result of the test with all the parameters.  You are correct that most of the time we just want to reraise. But there are context in which this pattern is needed.

Comment: Can't you just use a normal function that takes the function and the list of parameters and does the loop with all the logic?

Comment: ok, thanks. I am not sure it helps, but have you considered placing the loop inside the context manager, and have `ErrorhHandler` deal with the errors thrown & collected upon `exit`?

Comment: You could have `runTest` raise custom `BreakException`s and `ContinueException`s that the `try` statement in the `for` loop interprets appropriately: `except BreakException: break`, etc.

Comment: > ok, thanks. I am not sure it helps, but have you considered placing the loop inside the context manager, and have ErrorhHandler deal with it on exit? @ReblochonMasque

I don't think you can put a loop inside a context manager.

Comment: Most file reading or writing contain a loop inside a context manager; I don't clearly see why this would not be possible in your case.

Comment: @BlackBear that'd be essentially the same as the `assert_all_test` approach above. The test function cannot contain `continue` or `break` statements. Although @chepner's idea of using custom exception should work. But it'd be nice to have a pattern that other dev can use without importing and raising all custom exception when all they really want is `continue` and `break`.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque, I misunderstood. I thought you meant a loop inside __enter__ phase of the CM.  Simple `with cm(): for x in iter: block(x)` does not work because when block raises an exception to be caught by `cm` it exits the loop.

Comment: @vimsical if you do a break _inside_ a function, you won't interrupt any loops _outside_ of it..

Comment: @BlackBear exactly.  Therefore the approach of taking a function and call it on a list of parameter only works if the loop block can be refactor into a function, which might not be possible, if `continue` or `break` are present.

Answer (score 2):

How about a little class that only does the one thing you find yourself doing over and over:

```
class TestTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.error_list = []

    def do_test(self, f, p):
        try:
            f(p)
        except Exception as e:
            self.error_list.append(e)

def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    if exc_value is not None:
        self.error_list.append(exc_value)
        return True

def test(params):
    tt = TestTracker()
    for p in params:
        tt.do_test(run_test, p)
    assert isEmpty(tt.error_list), 'error encountered: {}'.format(tt.error_list)

def test2(params):
    tt = TestTracker()
    for p in params:
        with tt:
           # a block of code with loop control statements
           pass
    assert isEmpty(tt.error_list), 'error encountered: {}'.format(tt.error_list)
```

I modified this answer to make the class a context manager.  The `test2` shows how that can be used with loop control statements.  If no exception is raised within the context, the arguments to `__exit__` will be None.

You could even mix `with` statements and calls to `do_test`.
Python can do anything!

#### Edits :

Add some convenience to `TestTracker`

```
class TestTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.error_list = []

    def do_test(self, f, p):
        try:
            f(p)
        except Exception as e:
            self.error_list.append(e)

    def __bool__(self):
        return len(self.error_list) == 0

    def __str__(self):
        return 'error encountered: {}'.format(self.error_list)

def test(params):
    tt = TestTracker()
    for p in params:
        tt.do_test(run_test, p)
    assert tt, str(tt)
```

Comment: This is nice, but does not address when the test block cannot be easily wrapped into a `run_test` function because it contains loop flow control statements.

Btw, one can also do the `assert` in `TestTracker.__del__` so that it automatically assert when the local variable goes out of scope.

Comment: I don't like the idea of putting the assert statement in `__del__`.  That function doesn't run when the name goes out of scope but rather when the object is about to be destroyed.  Not the same thing, and in principle not under the programmer's direct control.  Also (from the docs): "It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits."

Comment: After some thoughts, I agree. I think we can do assert at `__exit__` so that the above pattern become `with TestTracker() as tt: for p in params: ...`

Comment: I modified my answer to support a context manager.  This ought to work with blocks of code containing `continue` and `break`,  As I wrote it the context manager goes inside the loop, wrapping a block of test code, not outside as in your comment.

Comment: But during each loop iteration doesn't a new `TestTracker` instance gets created and therefore a black `error_list`? How did the CM-in-loop worked for you?

EDIT: Never mind. Let me read your new answer again.

Comment: The TestTracker instance is created outside the loop, so there is only one.  At any point inside the loop you can start a context manager, which will store (and not propagate) any exception that occurs inside its block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156968/discussion-between-vimsical-and-paul-cornelius).